# How to remove the following error : ImportError: cannot import name 'normalize_data_format'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting stuck by sequential errors for the following code as you can see with the google colab link:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Tc8WEzqBMRd0Eg7pJijI98eBEKTw45s3?usp=sharing

you can get access the code from GitHub if it is not visible to you: https://github.com/nephashi/GaitRecognitionCNN

how do I make it resolve?

I am getting following errors:

2021-02-06 17:03:14.551645: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/content/sample_data/GaitRecognitionCNN-master/main.py", line 5, in 
from layers.Conv2D121 import Conv2D121
File "/content/sample_data/GaitRecognitionCNN-master/layers/Conv2D121.py", line 13, in 
from keras.utils.conv_utils import normalize_data_format
ImportError: cannot import name 'normalize_data_format'

If somehow I resolved it the next error in appearing, all solution present on the internet becomes old while keras and tensorflow lib have been changed so those solution not working always.

Please make resolve all next error if you are getting, I would be very grateful to you, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Replace import statement from

```
from keras.utils import conv_utils
```

to

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import conv_utils
```